# Should I use multiple files or combine pages into one file?

Tags: html

This question betrays how much of a novice I am. I'm making a website, and I'm wondering - is it okay to have separate html files for the distinct pages of my website, or should I try to combine them into one html file? I'm curious about the general way of doing things.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take account about 2 things here here:

**#1 HTTP Request Header** (A single file is better)

For each request the client will do to display you website, some informations are sent in additional of the content (example Headers)

Look like that (from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039)):

```
GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1
Host: net.tutsplus.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=r2t5uvjq435r4q7ib3vtdjq120
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

So, every new file (http, css, images, js, ...) will add more headers, or meta-data and will slow down request..

**#2 Browser cache** (Multiples files are better)

Files who never change on your website (like Logo, or main CSS file) have no need to be reloaded on every page, and can be placed on the browser cache.
So, create multiple file for "global" code are a good way to "avoid" loading code on every pages.

**Conclusion**

Both are good, every case have a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a proxy administrator, I am sometimes astounded by how many separate files are requested for a single web page.  In the old days, that could be trouble.  Good browsers today use an HTTP CONNECT to establish a single TCP tunnel in which to pass those requests.  Also, it's quite common for services to distribute content across multiple servers, each of which would require its own CONNECT.  And, for more heavily accessed services only line, there will often be the use of content delivery network to better manage the load and abuse from malicious sources.  These days, it's best to organize content across files according to the structure of the document, along with version control and other management considerations.

Comment: Arthur's point about cache is also important (voted up).  Proxies sometimes do caching as well, providing the benefit of caching to all users behind a particular proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is more an art than a science. You can break your content up in whatever seems to you a logical fashion, but as much as possible you want to try to view the site through the eyes of your users. That can mean actual research (surveys, focus groups, etc.) if you can afford it, or trying to draw inferences from Google Analytics or some other tracking system.

There's also an SEO angle. More pages can equate to greater presence in search engines, but if you overdo it you wind up with what Google terms "thin content" — pages with very little meat to them which don't convey much information.

This isn't really a question with a right or wrong answer. It's very much dependent on what you wish to accomplish both aesthetically and in terms of usability, performance, etc. The best answer comes with experience, but you can always copy sites you like until you get a feel for it.